# Best way to write refresher thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Hello I have some configurations those are to be refreshed after configurable time span. What is the best way of doing this or following will suffice ?

```
@Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            while(true){
                if (isRefreshNeeded) {
                    refresh()
                }
            }
        }
        catch( Exception excep )
        {
            // Log and report exception 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a Timer class, that's what it is for.

Using your code won't be a good idea as it will keep iterating all the time thereby consuming CPU cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using Timer class :

```
long initialDelay = 100; // In millis
    long delay  = 1000; // In millis

    Timer timer = new Timer("Refresher thread");
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // code to refresh the configurations

        }
    }, initialDelay, delay);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than refreshing after some time span using `Timer`/`TimerTask` or the more modern `ScheduledExecutorService`/`Runnable` method, you should perhaps establish a causal link between change and refresh using a Listener (a.k.a. Observer) pattern.
If you are more comfortable with code like you posted, you should at least use `Thread.sleep()` at the end of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

One of the cleanest options exist in java.utl.concurrent's ScheduledExecutorService#scheduleAtFixedRate

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) is the API documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/

I believe its already enough simplified to be used easily.